# Created a simulation of 5 card hands to see probability of royal flush

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>

int main() {
int i, n, j, a, g;
int d=0;
int k=0;
int hold[5];
time_t t;
typedef struct card{
    int suit;
    int value;
} cards;
struct card deck[52];
struct card *hand=malloc(sizeof(char));

n = 5;
void shuffle(cards *array, size_t q) {

    if (q>1) {
        size_t w;
            for (w = 0; w < q - 1; w++)
                {
                    srand(time(NULL));
                    size_t e = w + rand() / (RAND_MAX/ (q - w) + 1);
            cards t = array[e];
            array[e] = array[w];
            array[w] = t;
        }
    }
}

for (g=0; g < 1000000; g++) { // the for loop that controls how many times this simulation occurs

    for (i=0; i<13; i++) {// the following for loops create a deck in order (Ace to King spades, Ace to King clubs, etc)
        deck[i].suit = 1;
        deck[i].value =i+1;
    }

    for (i=13; i < 26; i++) {
        deck[i].suit = 2;
        deck[i].value = i - 12;
    }

    for (i=26; i < 39; i++) {
        deck[i].suit = 3;
        deck[i].value = i - 25;
    }
    for (i=39; i < 52; i++) {
        deck[i].suit = 4;
        deck[i].value = i - 38;
    }



for (i=0; i < 1; i++) // shuffles the deck by randomizing deck[i]{
shuffle(deck, 53);
}

j=51;

for (i=0; i < n; i++) { // deals 5 random cards to a persons hand
    srand(time(NULL));
    k = rand()%j;
    hand[i] = deck[k];
    if (k != j) {
        deck[k] = deck[j];
    }
    j = j-1;
}


for (i=0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j < n; j++) {
        if (hand[i].value > hand[j].value) {
            a = hand[i].value;
            hand[i].value = hand[j].value;
            hand[j].value = a; //organizes the persons hand from smallest to largest card values
        }
    }
}
if (hand[4].value == 13 && hand[3].value == 12 && hand[2].value == 11 && hand[1].value == 10 && hand[0].value == 9) {        if (hand[4].suit == hand[3].suit && hand[4].suit == hand[2].suit && hand[4].suit == hand[1].suit && hand[4].suit == hand[0].suit) {
        d++;
        // since the hand is organized from smallest to largest, if hand[5] is Ace, hand[4] is king etc, then we have a hand that goes from 10 to Ace (smallest to largest, 10 is actually 9 in this case). If all of the suit values are the same, then we have a royal flush. Therefore, increment variable d.
    }
}
}
// do that however many times, and after it is done print d.
printf("%d\n", d);
return (0);
}
```

The problem with my code is that it always prints d = 0. I run the simulation upwards 10 million times, but still d is 0. The probability of being dealt a royal flash is 1 in 649,740 so I should expect to see a few flushes if I run it that many times. Is there an error in my code?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you should call `srand(time(NULL));` only once in your program.

Comment: Upon first  glance, your "royal flush checking" logic seems fine (but can be refactored way better). Your issue is most likely with your RNG. As @mch said, only seed it once. Also, rand() is a PSEUDO-random number generator and it's possible that it *never* generate the exact random numbers for you to get d.

Comment: This does not even compile. You have function `shuffle()` within `main()`.

Comment: `struct card *hand=malloc(sizeof(char));` will allocate 1 byte of memory.

Comment: You are much better off just using `uint8_t` for the card, and having functions that extract the suit and rank as needed.

Comment: If you're selecting the hand by choosing 5 random numbers in the deck, then there is no need to shuffle the deck beforehand

Comment: calling `srand(time(NULL));` so much probably ensures that your program generates the same hand over and over

Comment: A much easier approach would be, `for(N times) {Shuffle_the_Deck; Check_the_first_five_cards;}`. No need to deal a separate hand. And as @M.M said, you're picking the same card most of the time. Check it out and see, after all, 5_of_a_kind is stronger than a Royal flush! But hey, you're cheating!!! :P

Answer (score 0):

Insufficient memory allocated.  [@Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948594/created-a-simulation-of-5-card-hands-to-see-probability-of-royal-flush#comment55656349_33948594)

Rather than allocating 1 `char` for `hand`, code should allocate enough for 5 `card`.

```
// struct card *hand = malloc(sizeof(char));
n = 5;
struct card *hand = malloc(sizeof *hand * 5);
```

... or simply

```
struct card hand[5];
```

---

Code excessive calls `srand(time(NULL));`.  Best to call `srand()` only once.  Each call resets the random number sequence.  Calling `srand()` will the same value (same time) will generate the same sequence of results from `rand()`.  [@M.M](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33948594/created-a-simulation-of-5-card-hands-to-see-probability-of-royal-flush/33949629#comment55656612_33948594)

---

Local definition of `void shuffle(cards *array, size_t q)` inside `main()` is not standard C.

--

Odds of royal flush are 1 in 649,740.  A simulation 1,000,000 hands may be insufficient.